# How to find the dominant color on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, paint

I am trying to create a game. There two players that are represented by two rectangles. The two rectangles move continuously and can redirected using WASD and Up,Down,Left,Right keys. Each rectangle leaves a trail of its own color wherever it goes. The goal of the game is to color the majority of the panel with your color under a time limit. I have an idea how to do everything except the part where I make the game tell me which is the most occurring color. It doesn't seem like there exists a method that does this so is there a way around this???

Comment: I don't think you should determine which player is winning by looking at the GUI. The GUI should only be responsible for painting the results. You should have a different way of tracking the areas painted by each player, and use that to determine what to paint.

Answer (score 0):

When the game finishes you can create a `BufferedImage` of the panel with code something like:

```
Dimension size = panel.getSize()
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
panel.paint( g2d );
```

Then you can iterate through all the pixels in the `BufferedImage` using the `getRGB(...)` method. Then you track the pixels of each player.

Edit:

Before painting the panel onto a BufferedImage you can hard code some painting to see if your algorithm is working correctly.

For example:

```
//panel.paint( g2d );
g2d.setColor( Color.RED );
g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, 5, 5);
g2d.setColor( Color.GREEN);
g2d.fillRect( 20, 20, 10, 10);
// now test your algorithm.
```

Since you know the size of the rectangle you just painted you should know the expected output of your algorithm. Once it works with hardcoded data, you then test it with your random drawings confident that it works.

Comment: I tried it like this. The result confuses me due to its lack of definiteness.`for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<700; j++) {
     int pixel= image.getRGB(i, j);
     if(pixel==new Color(255, 0, 0).getRGB())
      p1++;
     if(pixel==new Color(0, 255, 0).getRGB())
      p2++; 
    }
   }` Sorry, this is new to me so I'm not sure if it's right.

Comment: @ArcIX 1) Don't keep creating new Color objects. Create your red and green Color object outside the loop and get its int value outside the loop. Then inside the loop you just do the comparison. 2)  `I'm not sure if it's right.` - that is why you do testing. Start with a small area, maybe of 5x5 rectangle of one color and see what the result is. Then add two areas. See edit.